# Link to Current Page in Django, with Additional GET Params?

Tags: django, url

How do I place an HTML link what refers to the *current* page, **and** which adds **additional** GET parameters (or overwriting existing ones, if they already exist)?

Right now I have something like:

```
 <a href="{{ request.path }}?Key=Value"> My Link </a>
```

Currently, `request` is passed to the page. If `request.path` is https://stackoverflow.com/, then the resulting link becomes https://stackoverflow.com/?Key=Value

#### The problem?

But of course, if the current URL is https://stackoverflow.com/?PrevKey=PrevValue then it becomes:

> https://stackoverflow.com/?PrevKey=PrevValue?Key=Value

**Notice the incorrect second question mark** -- it should in fact be:

> https://stackoverflow.com/?PrevKey=PrevValue&Key=Value

Furthermore, if there is *already* a key with the same name, then instead of overwriting it, my current solution ignores it -- which is wrong.

How do I solve these two problems?

Comment: Can you programmatically send key value pair to the template instead of hard coding it in there? Also, is the `request` the same request that gets sent to the view? Finally, is this key-value pair to be on all links?

Comment: @ladaghini: (1) I'd rather not, if at all possible. (2) Yes. (3) No, the links would have different key-value pairs (since they control different settings on my page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a custom tag. There are a couple on djangosnippets - [this one](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2428/) looks pretty comprehensive.

Comment: @Daniel: Oh cool! Seems to be exactly what I need. Thanks a lot! :) +1

Comment: @Daniel: It's exactly what I need, with a caveat -- This doesn't work: `{% add_get {{field_name}}={{field_value}} %}`. How do I make a variable's value be the parameter name?

Comment: No need to use variable tags inside a tag - you would just do `{% add_get field_name=field_value %}`. But it looks like that only works for the value - you'll need to change line 38 to use `params[key.resolve(context)]` on the left-hand side.

Comment: @Daniel: For some reason that doesn't work -- I get "Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'resolve'"

Comment: Ah, sorry, looks like you'll also need to change line 48 - `values[ parser.compile_filter(s[0])] =`

Comment: @Daniel: Unfortunately now I'm getting `Caught TypeError while rendering: unhashable type: 'list'`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone seeing this in future: https://bitbucket.org/monwara/django-url-tools

Answer (score 0):

You can use: {{ request.get_full_path }} to get the current path with additional parameters.

Comment: Well the problem is *adding* parameters, not *getting* the existing ones.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't read your question carefully enough. The link that @Daniel provided to Django Snippets is most likely your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a beginner with Django, so you'll have to take my response with a grain of salt.

Firstly, `request.path` should return the path to the page without the domain, according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path). So if the request is for http://example.com/, `request.path` should be just `"/"`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

But that's not relevant. More importantly, `request.path` won't have any query parameters, so if the page requested is http://example.com/?PrevKey=PrevValue, then `request.path` will still be `"/"`. If you want to get the query parameters, you have to make use of the dictionary-like access of the GET and POST properties (in this case GET) of the `request` object. Or better yet, access them through the [QueryDict methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/request-response/#id3).

What I would do here, and this is by no means the best method nor code, is to prepare a custom template filter in which you pass the current request object and the key-value pair to test against.

This is how your template code would look. Note that you can still hard code the key value pair, although here it is formatted as a string with "key colon value". The filter function can handle (if you need to) more than just one set of key-value pairs.

```
<a href="{{ request | addQueryParameter:'Key:Value'}}">My Link</a>
```

The filter function:

```
from urllib import urlencode

def addQueryParameter(request, parameter):
    # parse the key-value pair(s) in parameter (which looks like a JSON string)
    # then add to dictionary d
    # note i am not taking into account white-space.
    for param in string.split(','):
        key, value = param.split(':', 1)
        d[key] = value

    # check if any keys in d are already in the request query parameters
    # if so, delete from d. If I misunderstood your question, then refactor 
    # to delete from request.GET instead:
    for key in d.keys():
        if key in request.GET.keys():
             del d[key]

    # add the keys in request.GET into d:
    d.extend(request.GET.items())

    # convert dictionary of key value pairs into a query string for urls, 
    # prepend a ?
    queryString = "?%s" % urlencode(d)
    return "%s%s" % (request.path, queryString if queryString else "")
```

I should point out that if the request is for the page http://example.com/login/?prev=news and your template looks like

```
<a href="{{ request | addQueryParameter:'goto:dashboard,feature:products'}}">My Link</a>
```

Then the output would be (hopefully, if it works):

```
<a href="/login/?prev=news&goto=dashboard&feature=products">
My Link</a>
<!-- the order of the above parameters may differ -->
```

Note that there is no domain (i.e. the http://example.com/ part) in this link. That is because the filter doesn't add it. But you can modify it to do so.

I'll leave it to you to [register this template filter](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter09/#cn166). More [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). Hope this helps.

Comment: You should really avoid camelcase in Python. addQueryParameter => add_query_parameters.

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript solution is much suitable in this case.
Example :

```
 <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a page_number="1">First Page</a>
                <a page_number="{{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Last Page</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if page_obj.has_previous or page_obj.has_next %}
                <span class="current">{{ page_obj.number }}/{{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}</span>
            {% endif %}
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a page_number="{{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Page</a>
                <a page_number="{{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">End Page</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.querySelectorAll('.pagination a').forEach(link => {
            let page_number = link.getAttribute('page_number');
            const gotopageUrl = new URL(location.href);
            gotopageUrl.searchParams.set("page", page_number);
            link.href = gotopageUrl.href;
        });
        </script>
    </div>
```